# Como quebrar linha automaticamente em um componente de texo?

Tags: java, swing

Eu gostaria que, quando alcançasse o número máximo de letras/palavras naquela linha, quebrasse automaticamente.

Quando eu coloco uma pizza funciona tranquilamente:

[image: Quando eu coloco uma pizza funciona tranquilamente.]

Mas Quando eu coloco mais de uma pizza o texto fica maior que a jLabel aí não dá pra ver todas as pizzas nem o total:

[image: Mas Quando eu coloco mais de uma pizza o texto fica maior que a jLabel aí não dá pra ver todas as pizzas nem o total.]

Meu código:

```
 private void btnAdicionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //Verificar se o local de entrega foi duplamente selecionado ou se nenhum

    if(((checkLocal.isSelected()) && (checkCasa.isSelected())) ||((checkLocal.isSelected()==FALSE) && (checkCasa.isSelected()==FALSE)) ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Foram escolhidos dois locais de entrega ou nenhum foi selecionado.\nPor favor verifique o local de entrega");
    }else if(checkLocal.isSelected()){

    String Entregar =checkLocal.getText();
    }else if(checkCasa.isSelected()){

    String Entregar =checkCasa.getText();
    }

    //Os dados foram verificados


    String Nome      = txtNomeVenda.getText();
    String Endereco  = txtEndereco.getText();
    String Sabor1    = (String) SaborPizza1.getSelectedItem();
    String Sabor2    = (String) SaborPizza2.getSelectedItem();   
    String Borda     = (String) BordaEscolha.getSelectedItem();
    String SaborTodo = "";


    if(Borda.equals("Nenhuma")){
    Borda = "";
    }

    if(Sabor2.equals("Nenhum")){
    SaborTodo = "1 "+Sabor1+" Borda:"+Borda;
    }else{
    SaborTodo = " 1/2"+Sabor1+" 1/2"+Sabor2+" \nBorda:"+Borda;
    }

    PizzaNota.setText(PizzaNota.getText()+"\n"+SaborTodo+"");

    txtNomeNota.setText(txtNomeVenda.getText());
}
```

Comment: Outra coisa, use JTextField se precisa quebrar linha, não JLabel. Esse componente foi feito para textos curtos.

Comment: Tem uma jLabel alí onde tá escrito "Pizzas:" e o objetivo era mostrar todas as pizzas que foram pedidas, mas quando eu adiciono mais de uma pizza a jLabel aumenta e não dá pra ver nada

Comment: Esse trecho não é executável.

Comment: Como eu disse, JLabel não é para utilizar para textos longos e quebras de linhas, por isso existe o JTextArea, que permite quebras de linhas e longos textos.

Comment: Como assim ele não é executável??

Comment: Ah entendeu vou tentar, obrigado de novo kkkk

Comment: Você precisa fornecer um exemplo do seu código que as pessoas possam copiar e executar para ver o problema.

Comment: Tudo bem, é que eu sou meio novo no Stack, tô aprendendo a usar ainda kkkk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JLabels também aceitam tags html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html), apesar de ser uma solução porca que se mal usada, deixará seu código difícil de ler e de dar manutenção, para casos esporádicos você pode usar da forma abaixo:

```
PizzaNota.setText("<html>"+PizzaNota.getText()+"<br>"+SaborTodo+"</html>");
```

Isso quebrará o texto entre as duas strings concatenadas no `JLabel`.

---

Utilizando [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) fica bem mais fácil, uma vez que ele já possui métodos que você define para que ele quebre a linha automaticamente, através do [`JTextArea#setLineWrap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap-boolean-), e juntamente com esse método, você pode também configurar o componente para que quebre a linha e o texto corretamente, evitando quebrar uma palavra que não caiba no final da linha, com o método [`JTextArea#setWrapStyleWord`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord-boolean-). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class JTextAreaQuebraLinhaTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JTextAreaQuebraLinhaTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public JTextAreaQuebraLinhaTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 300));

        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        this.contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);

        this.textArea = new JTextArea(5, 15);
        // quebra a linha ao chegar no limite
        // da textarea
        this.textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        // define a quebra de linha sem quebrar
        // a palavra no final da linha, caso
        // nao caiba inteira
        this.textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.textArea);
        this.contentPane.add(this.scrollPane);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Testando a quebra de linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Downvoter, por gentileza informar qual o problema com a resposta. Senão de nada adianta seu voto, se eu não corrigir o problema, isso se este voto foi devido a isso.